Interpretation of linear regression results
I ran a linear regression model with 2 IVs (both are dichotomous) with an interaction:
y = a + b1x1 + b2x2 + b3x1x2

The model and only x1 were significant.Therefore, I ran a second model:
y = a + b1x1

This time, the model and x1 were insignificant.
In both cases, there was no assumption voilations.
How should I interpret the results?

How you select specification of the original model?

Why did you ditch the x2 and x1x2 features and rerun with just x1?

You don't, because these are not complete results. All you've told us are that you ran two models and what was significant. You didn't say how you chose these models, why you dropped the nonsignificant parts, what the parameter estimates were, what the standard errors of those estimates were, what the variables were, what the sample size was. ....   Dropping variables just because they are not significant is not recommended, although it is common. It is a form of backward selection.

My question is more in general and not for my specific results.
